# Send POST request from ember to specified URL

Tags: django, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I am new to full stack development, and having an issue with a web application I'm working on for my employer. I was tasked with creating a fairly simple application that we can scale over time. For now all that it needs to do is take data from one of our databases, and pass it to a front end application. Using this front-end app our workers should be able to double check the information passed in, and make sure it has been properly translated to a new format. After it is translated I want to send an HTTP POST request to our new systems back-end and have it add this new data via the REST API. Essentially it's an application that was used for practice to get me more acquainted with full stack development while making an effective tool to transfer mass data from one system to another. I can't seem to figure out how to set up something in ember.js to send that POST request to somewhere other than my back-end though.

Comment: What did you tried? Did you tried out a native `fetch` request? Or using `ember-ajax` to do a `jQuery.ajax()` request? Or is this question about customizing Ember Data to use multiple backends?

Comment: I haven't necessarily tried anything yet because as I said I'm still learning and didn't really know what to try in the first place. I wouldn't say I want it to have multiple back-end connections because I don't actually want people editing anything directly to the database. I just want the front end to be able to send REST requests to an external address. So say I take in data from my database and edit it. I then want to POST it to the url in charge of editing our new database which also utilizes a REST API

Answer (score 0):

I believe after re-reading the page on the ember.js site I found my answer. Sorry for posting a question that was already answered elsewhere. It was asked after a while of googling and not finding what sounded right. Just needed a day to let my brain reset I guess. In any case, if somebody else stumbles upon this post and (like me) wasn't comprehending at the time, the answer lies here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/

You simply create a new adapter with the host you want to send requests to. Then you can create a new model in my case to serialize the data in a way the host will understand what you're trying to transfer to it. This will allow for data migration between sources like I desired. Sorry again for the unnecessary post, but hopefully it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: You are referencing a very outdated version of the guides. It's for Ember 1.10 which was released years ago. You could find the current version for customizing Ember Data adapters here: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/ Using a plain `fetch` is another option which is much less complex if it's only about sending one POST request and you don't need a fully-featured client-side ORM like Ember Data.